# Problems with making a forecast fanchart in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to replicate the inflation forecast fanchart for Argentina. I build a bivariate VAR model with Argentina's monthly inflation rate and interest rate. I estimate the VAR in a standard form. Then, from random number generation I try to plot different trajectories to build the fanchart. But I get an error:

```
Error using * Inner matrix dimensions must agree. enter code here
```

I have searched for the error but I don't understand what is wrong. My code is as follows:

´´´

```
clear;
clc;
% Load data
data = xlsread('base_arg_var','forecast','A1:C205'); % Change file name as appropriate

% Specify VAR model order and horizon
p = 2;
horizon = 4;

% Estimate VAR model using historical data
var_model = varm(size(data,2),p);
var_est = estimate(var_model, data); 

% Generate Monte Carlo simulations
num_sims = 1000;
T = size(data,1);
simulated_data = zeros(T + horizon, size(data,2), num_sims);
for i = 1:num_sims
    % Generate random errors from estimated covariance matrix
    eps = mvnrnd(zeros(1,size(data,2)), var_est.Covariance, horizon);
    % Initialize simulation with historical data
    simulated_data(1:T,:,i) = data;
    % Simulate future path of VAR variables
    for t = T+1:T+horizon
        y_lags = reshape(simulated_data(t-1:-1:t-p,:),[],1);
        y_sim = var_est.AR{1}*y_lags + eps(t-T,:);
        simulated_data(t,:,i) = reshape(y_sim,[],size(data,2));
    end
end

% Compute mean and variance of forecasts across all simulations
forecast_mean = zeros(horizon,size(data,2));
forecast_var = zeros(horizon,size(data,2));
for h = 1:horizon
    forecast_mean(h,:) = mean(simulated_data(T+h,:,end-num_sims+1:end),3);
    forecast_var(h,:) = var(simulated_data(T+h,:,end-num_sims+1:end),0,3);
end

% Calculate quantiles for fan chart
quantiles = [0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95];
forecast_quantiles = zeros(horizon,size(data,2),length(quantiles));
for h = 1:horizon
    for i = 1:size(data,2)
        forecast_quantiles(h,i,:) = quantile(simulated_data(T+h,i,end-num_sims+1:end), quantiles);
    end
end

% Plot results
figure;
for i = 1:size(data,2)
    subplot(size(data,2),1,i);
    plot(data(:,i));
    hold on;
    plot(T+1:T+horizon, forecast_mean(:,i), 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
    for q = 1:length(quantiles)
        patch([T+1:T+horizon, fliplr(T+1:T+horizon)], ...
              [squeeze(forecast_quantiles(:,i,q))', fliplr(squeeze(forecast_quantiles(:,i,end-q+1))')], ...
              'b', 'FaceAlpha', 0.1, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
    end
    legend('Data', 'Forecast', '95% Fan Chart');
    title(sprintf('Variable %d', i));
end
```

´´´